# How fix Authentication failed for git repository without SSH method

Tags: git, github

Although I didn't enable 2 factor authintication, suddenly I am having `Authentication failed for...` issue. I tried many **command** & method but can't do push my codes.
How can I do this with HTTPS way. I use **Linux (Ubuntu)** that's why I cant remove **Credential**. How can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Check first:

- your remote URL: `git remote -v`
- your credential helper: `git config credential.helper`

If you are using an HTTPS URL, *and* a credential helper, it is possible the wrong credential was stored by the helper.
For testing, deactivate said helper, just to check your current username/token is working.